# Unusual indentation

Tags: html, css

On my site, [matprichardson.co.uk](http://matprichardson.co.uk), when you click the 'help' button in the dialog in the center of the screen, another dialog pops up containing some content.

For some reason, when this happens, the first two lines of the first paragraph element are strangely indented, as well as the header, which is normally centered.

[image]

I've looked at my markup and css a number of times now and I'm really struggling to see why this is happening.  Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

CSS

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

```
#maincontainer {
  font-family: arial;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dialog {
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}


.dialog p, .dialog ul {
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 12px;
}

.dialogtitle h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 0;
  font-family: "courier new";
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.dialogtitle {
  cursor: move;
}

.dialogcontent {
  margin: 10px;
}

.windowsbutton{
  width: 70px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: "courier new";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-width:2px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}

.buttonsurround {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 70px;
  border-radius:3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.buttonselected {
  border-width: 2px;
}

.windowsbutton:focus {
  outline: none;
}


#maindialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}

#helpdialog {
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 110px;
}

#helpClose {
    margin:0 200px;
}


/*Menu*/
#menu {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}



/*Icons*/
.iconcontainer {
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.iconcontainer:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.foldericon {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.iconhead {
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color:black;
}

.foldertext {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.iconcontainer h1 {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Mat Richardson</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="maincontainer">

        <div id="menu">

        </div>

        <!--an icon.  Lovely, isn't it?-->
        <div class="iconcontainer" id="blog">
            <div class="foldericon">
                <div class="iconhead">
                </div>
                <div class="iconmain">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="foldertext">
                <h1>blog</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="iconcontainer" id="pictures">
            <div class="foldericon">
                <div class="iconhead">
                </div>
                <div class="iconmain">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="foldertext">
                <h1>pics</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="iconcontainer" id="websites">
            <div class="foldericon">
                <div class="iconhead">
                </div>
                <div class="iconmain">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="foldertext">
                <h1>websites</h1>
            </div>
        </div>







        <div id="maindialog" class="dialog">
            <div class="dialogtitle">
                <h2>Welcome to matprichardson.co.uk</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="dialogcontent">
                <div class="buttonsurround buttonselected"><input type="button" id="mainOK" value="OK" class="windowsbutton" /></div>
                <div class="buttonsurround"><input type="button" value="Cancel" id="mainCancel" class="windowsbutton" /></div>
                <div class="buttonsurround"><input type="button" value="H&#818elp" id="mainHelp" class="windowsbutton" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="helpdialog" class="dialog">
            <div class="dialogtitle">
                <h2>Help</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="dialogcontent">
                <p>Welcome to the personal site of Mat Richardson.  There's not much to see right now,
                but do feel free to have a click about.</p>
                <p>Some links you might want to visit (or not, your choice):</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://2toria.com">2toria</a> (another site I own)</li>
                    <li><a href="http://codepen.io/2toria/">My Codepen Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1373484/mat-richardson">My StackOverflow Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/matprichardson">My twitter account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=117558046&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile">My LinkedIn Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="helpClose" class="buttonsurround buttonselected"><input type="button" value="Close" class="windowsbutton" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: Done...really struggling with this one. I'm sure it's straightforward but I just can't see the solution.

Comment: This is because the dialog is positioned `relative`ly and it is still in document normal flow. Therefore the content wraps the floated icons which are at the left-top of the page. Positioning the dialog box `absolute`ly will fix the problem.

Comment: @HashemQolami - this worked perfectly.  Add as an answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594834/unusual-indentation/28595093#comment45496605_28594834):

> This is because the dialog is positioned `relative`ly and it is still in
>   document normal flow. Therefore the content wraps the floated icons
>   which are at the left-top of the page.

Positioning the dialog box absolutely will fix the problem.

---

Alternatively, you can add `clear: both` declaration to the dialog element in order for clearing the floats. Thus the content of `relative` positioned dialog won't wrap the floated icons anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the position property for your blog, websites,and pics divs is set to relative and therefore it's taking up space. Change it so that they're set to absolute, and the text on your help dialog goes back to normal.

You could add something like:

```
#blog, #pictures, #websites {
    position:absolute;
}
#blog {
    left:20px;
}
#pictures {
    left:80px;
}
#websites {
    left:140px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7djgrhdn/)**

Comment: That is correct of course; however it would possibly make more sense to leave those icons as they are, and absolutely position the dialog instead.

Comment: This works, but I'm going to go with the solution of absolutely positioning the dialog.